# difference between process explorer and task manager

Tags: windows-7, taskmanager, process-explorer

below is screen capture of process explorer(left) and task manager(right) in windows 7.
process list in task manager is sorted with PID.
as you can see some processes(csrss.exe, wininit.exe, services.exe...) are missing in
task manager window.

can someone explain why?

[image: processexp vs taskmgr]

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Windows 7`'s Task Manager only shows the processes running under the currently logged on user.

Click on the `Show processes from all users` button below to see system processes as well.

Comment: oh.. how fool am I.. thank you!

Comment: Ah, it happens to everyone mate :) Anyway, here's a quick tip. If you find Process Explorer a bit confusing and Task Manager too basic then in your task manager go to `Performance` tab and click on `Resource Monitor` button. I've found that it provides enough information and you may not feel the need to use third party process monitors any more.